# How can I check a folder and subfolder in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to check the contents of a folder, for example, C:\Temp if contains pictures, run a scheduled task, but ignore any folders or other file types within C:\Temp and write the output to a log file.

I then need to be able to check a subfolder within C:\temp i.e. C:\Temp\myfolder. If folder is empty, write to log file and do nothing. Else if subfolder contains picture files, move them one level up to C:\Temp, run a scheduled task and write to a log file. All file types other than picture files should be ignored.

I have tried:

```
if((Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -force | Where-Object Extension -in ('.bmp','.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.tiff') | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0){
    Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName Notepad
}else{
    Write-Output "No files found."
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the bits that work individually? And perhaps describe what happens when you try to combine them?

Comment: Try : if(Test-Path -Path C:\Temp\myfolder)
{
   Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Temp\myfolder\*.jpg' | foreach { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName 'C:\Temp\'$_.Name}
}

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Copy your code and paste here

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Unclear as to why I cannot copy and paste code in the usual fashion, but I’m adding a screenshot of what I’ve tried so far to my original post.

Comment: @RobertGething Please give pasting another go - [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76557654/edit), add a new-line or two at the bottom, paste everything as-is - we can help you format the code afterwards :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I’ve now managed to add a code snippet to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is something like below:

```
# set these variables to your actual environment
$sourceFolder = 'C:\Temp'
$imageTypes   = '*.jpg','*.jpeg','*.png','*.bmp','*.gif','*.tiff'  # etc.
$logFile      = 'X:\Somewhere\mylog.log'

# first run, just the sourcefolder
$imageFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File -Include $imageTypes
$filesFound = @($imageFiles).Count
if ($filesFound -eq 0) {
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "No images found in $sourceFolder" -PassThru
}
else {
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$sourceFolder contains $filesFound image files" -PassThru
    # run your scheduled task
    Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName Notepad -Verbose
}

# next see if there are image files in the subfolder
$subFolder  = Join-Path -Path $sourceFolder -ChildPath 'MyFolder'
$imageFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $subFolder -File -Include $imageTypes
$filesFound = @($imageFiles).Count
if ($filesFound -eq 0) {
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "No images found in $subFolder" -PassThru
}
else {
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value "$subFolder contains $filesFound image files" -PassThru
    # move the files to the source folder
    $imageFiles| ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $sourceFolder
    }
    # run your scheduled task
    Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName Notepad -Verbose
}
```